# Cypher quering using a node Id

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-graph

Lets assume the following entities:

A 'user' has a 'blog' and the blog has 'entries'. A blog can have multiple users and an entry has three properties, user, blog and a string entry. I want to write a cypher query that returns all the entries for a particular blog and user. I have both the user node id and the blog id. I can use the user id to start the node but how can the blog id be used? I don't have access to anything else which is unique, hence the node id is being used.

```
start user=(1) match (user)->[:BLOG]-(blog)->[:ENTRY](entry) where entry.blog = blogId return entry
```

Recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a note: In Neo4j 1.5 you can't use `START foo=(42) ...` You have to use `START foo=node(42) ...`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use parameters to pass in the blog and user-ids.

```
START user=({userId}), blog=({blogId}) MATCH user-[:BLOG]->blog-[:ENTRY]->entry RETURN entry
```

then execute the cypher query with a parameter-`Map` that contains `userId=1,blogId=2`.

If you have the blog-id you don't have to pass in the user. As you didn't specify a relationship between user and entry (like `AUTHOR`) it would return all the entries of the blog, which is probably not what you want.

```
START user=({userId}), blog=({blogId}) MATCH blog-[:ENTRY]->entry<-[:AUTHOR]-user RETURN entry
```

Answer (score 0):

At first your cypher query looks wrong, maybe other version than stable?

```
start user=(1) match (user)->[:BLOG]-(blog)->[:ENTRY](entry) where entry.blog = blogId return entry
```

If you have user id and blog id I think it you can try this out:

```
START user=(userId), blog=(blogId) MATCH user-[:BLOG]->blog-[:ENTRY]->entry RETURN entry
```

I think, in graph database using foreign key is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks Melug. I'll try your suggestion. I'm quite sure that the original query is valid.